# Uploading MP3/Video File

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

In my C# Project I tried to include media files. But when I tried to use the upload/download code that I successfully used for the image and document, did not went right. So can anyone help me out with the upload and download of the audio and video files.

My code: 
For upload:

```
if (musicFile.HasFile)
{
    musicFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(type) + "/" + musicFile.FileName);
    musicfile = musicFile.FileName;
}
```

For download:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("MP3/") + filename);
Response.End();
```

Please I need it fast...

Comment: i am using IIS 7.0. I tried to upload then the browser shows that the connection has been reset. But with image the upload is successful.

Comment: Did you make sure that the mime-type was properly set to audio/mp3 on the header of your response? Did you make sure that your IIS configuration has the extension mp3 registered as a valid extension for it to serve?

Comment: By the way, I have observed that in stackoverflow phrases like "URGENT" and "I need it fast" tend to have an effect opposed to the original intend...

Comment: @yms not only that, it undermines other questions. What, other questions are not as important? funny.

Answer (score 2):

Code for upload is correct but 2 points:
1. Make sure the address is right (type string)
2. You should set access for the folder you would uploading on the host

And for download you could easily provide a link pointing to your file:
`< a href="~/Music/MyFile.mp3">My Mp3< /a>`